# Customise android search view

Tags: android, android-layout, searchview, text-alignment, android-search

I have a search view that looks like the following

[image: search view]

I want it to resemble the following

[image]

Following is the code

```
<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:keyboardNavigationCluster="true"
    android:queryHint="@string/search_teams"
    android:textColor="@color/grey" />
```

I want to be able to left align and customize the query hint in the search view by changing the font. By default the text is center aligned, is there any way I can change that?

Comment: do you also want the speaker on the right?

Comment: Yes, Also with the search view underlined

Comment: You can use a simple editText with `drawableStart` and `drawableEnd`

Comment: `SerachView` is a widget/container, which internally uses many other view like textview and several other views inside to form the `SerachView` layout. What I would do is, read the SerachView class and find the `TextView` being used and then get a reference to that `TextView` by `searchView.findViewById(serachviewTextViewId)` and then apply the property to the `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify Searchable Configuration in a separate xml file and set below properties

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/search_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer" >
</searchable>
```

From documentation refer [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog#SearchableConfiguration) for more options

> You can add voice search functionality to your search dialog or widget
>   by adding the android:voiceSearchMode attribute to your searchable
>   configuration. This adds a voice search button that launches a voice
>   prompt.